# Add a hash to an AR object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I'm using simple form for a dropdown collection. The collection is:

```
@users.where(:role => 'admin')
```

I need to add an additional option which doesn't exist in the database. Something along the lines of:

```
user = { :id => 9999, :name => 'Finalize Deal' }
@users.push user
```

But it returns an error:

> undefined method `name' for {:id=>9999, :name=>"Finalize Deal"}:Hash

Any advice would be welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `User` object instead of a `Hash`

```
user = User.new({ :id => 9999, :name => 'Finalize Deal' })
```

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem:

```
@ar = @users.where(:role => "admin")
fake_user = User.new(:id => 9999, :name => "Finalize Deal")
@ar << fake_user
```

Or a one liner:

```
@ar = @users.where(:role => "admin") << User.new(:id => 9999, :name => "Finalize Deal")
```